# FFmpeg on Android with Rubberband

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

When I try to link librubberband.a I get:
libavfilter/af_rubberband.c:236: error: undefined reference to 'rubberband_set_pitch_scale'

1. I compiled rubberband for armv7a, and created a static library (rubberband.a).
   I checked the library, and It contained the needed symbols (using nm).
2. I verified that librubberband.a is in the libpath (-L)
3. I verified that extern C exists in the rubberband.c.h file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error happened in the link stage. Make sure the link directory has been added to `-L` parameters of your compiler.

`-L/directory/of/your/lib`

And specify the library with `-l` option.

So make sure the option `-L/directory/of/your/lib -lrubberband` set for your compiler when you build `ffmpeg` with `rubberband` support.

If you didn't use `pkg-config` to add the library. You can use the option `--extra-ldflags` to add when configure ffmpeg before build.

```
./configure \
# some configure options
--extra-ldflags="-L/directory/of/your/lib -lrubberband" \
# more configure options
```

If you use `pkg-config` to find out the libraries. Just add the `library.pc` directory to `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, and let the build system do the remaining.

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/directory/to/your/rubberband.pc
```

#### Updated

Finally make sure you link against to the same architecture of your library.

```
$ arm-linux-androideabi-readelf -h librubberband.a |grep 'Class\|Machine
```

For `armeabi-v7a`, it should be `ELF32` and `ARM`.

#### Updated

I have cloned the source of rubberband from https://bitbucket.org/breakfastquay/rubberband

And found the function call `rubberband_set_pitch_scale` is defined at `src/rubberband-c.cpp`, this file is not include in `Android.mk` when build for Android (WHY?).

So you have to add this file to build.

```
RUBBERBAND_SRC_FILES = ... \
    $(RUBBERBAND_SRC_PATH)/rubberband-c.cpp
```

After build done, you need to create directory structure like below

```
    .
├── include
│   └── rubberband
│       ├── RubberBandStretcher.h
│       └── rubberband-c.h
└── lib
    ├── librubberband.a
    └── pkgconfig
        └── rubberband.pc
```

The file `rubberband.pc` was copied from `rubberband.in.pc` with some minor changes.

```
prefix=/path/to/rubberband/install/root
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: rubberband
Version: 1.8.1
Description: 
Libs: -L${libdir} -lrubberband -L/path/to/android/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a -lgnustl_static
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

Then add

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/path/to/rubberband/install/root
```

before `./configure` to tell ffmpeg find `rubberband` by `pkg-config`.

I have tried with the latest ffmpeg, it works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
Of course I put the directory of the lib next to the -L
The -l is optional, the linker will search the -L path for a library (I tried it anyway, and it didn't help).

Eli

Comment: @Eli Where is your rubberband installed? How did you configure your build?

Comment: Its not "installed", I just produced the .a using Android.mk, and told the linker the location of it.

Comment: The Android.mk is this:

Comment: @Eli ok, how did you configure ffmpeg?

Comment: Its too long for a comment

Comment: ./configure --enable-cross-compile --arch=arm --target-os=linux --prefix=/output  --disable-shared --enable-static --cross-prefix=/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --sysroot=/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-14/arch-arm --enable-gpl --enable-memalign-hack  --enable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --enable-libx264 --enable-zlib --enable-librubberband --extra-cflags='-I../x264 -I../libmp3lame -I../rubberband/inc -mfloat-abi=softfp -march=armv7-a -w' --extra-ldflags='-L../rubberband -L../x264 -L../libmp3lame -lc'

Comment: The configure passed OK, also the compile stage.

Comment: I didn't see `-lrubberband` option in your `--extra-ldflags`

Comment: its because its optional, the linker finds without a problem the x264, and there is no -lx264

Comment: And I did tried it with the -l option (as I told you before), and It didn't help

Comment: Sorry to tackle you like that... Its a hard problem, I did all the obvious stuff yesterday ;)

Comment: Thank! its looks very promising, I can't use pkg-config since NDK does not have it? how did you managed to overcome it? (I just removed the check from the configure script)

Comment: I managed to solve the issue, and I accepted your answer, because it gave me great directions to try. I solved my issue by ignoring the ffmpeg linker issues, and link using the ndk-build with the added stl paths (I took the idea from your pkg-config). Thanks for all your help!!!

Comment: NDK doesn't support `pkg-config`, but `pkg-config` is necessary for ffmpeg build if you use the traditional way `./configure` to build. You just build rubberband library with NDK, then provide rubberband library to ffmpeg, and ffmpeg use `pkg-config` to find the provided rubberband library. Anyway, congratulate you solved the issue by your own.

Comment: @alijandro could you please help me how to use `--enable-rubberband` as suggested here https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#rubberband  command for FFmpeg.