# How to change or modify pitch of audio file (music etc like .mp3 file)using FFMPEG?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I want to change and modify pitch an .mp3 audio file using FFMPEG.
But I am unable to use FFMPEG to change or modify pitch of that sound.
what command (exact command) should be exactly use for changing pitch of an audio file?

```
 String outPutPath = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Share it Application/Over_the_HorizonTemp.wav").getPath();
                 
                String[] strFfmpeg  = {"ffmpeg","-i" ,strInputPath,"-af", "rubberband=tempo=1.0:pitch=1.5:pitchq=quality" ,outPutPath};
                execffmpegBinary(strFfmpeg);
```

execffmpegBinary Function:

```
public void execffmpegBinary(String[] command) {
    Config.enableLogCallback(new LogCallback() {
        @Override
        public void apply(LogMessage message) {
            Log.e(Config.TAG, message.getText());
            Log.e("TAG", "apply: " +message.getText());
        }
    });
    Config.enableStatisticsCallback(new StatisticsCallback() {
        @Override
        public void apply(Statistics statistics) {

        }
    });

    long executionId = FFmpeg.executeAsync(command, new ExecuteCallback() {
        @Override
        public void apply(long executionId, int returnCode) {
            if (returnCode == RETURN_CODE_SUCCESS) {
                
                Log.e("1TAG", "apply:return code "+returnCode );
                Log.e("1TAG", "apply:execution Id "+executionId );
                Log.e("1TAG", "apply:execution Id "+ new FFmpegExecution(executionId,command));


            } else if (returnCode == RETURN_CODE_CANCEL) {
                Log.e("2TAG", "apply:return code "+returnCode );
                Log.e("2TAG", "apply:execution Id "+executionId );
                Log.e("2TAG", "apply:execution Id "+ new FFmpegExecution(executionId,command));

            } else {
                Log.e("3TAG", "apply: returnCode"+ returnCode);
                Log.e("3TAG", "apply:return code "+returnCode );
                Log.e("3TAG", "apply:execution Id "+executionId );
                Log.e("3TAG", "apply:execution Id "+ new FFmpegExecution(executionId,command));

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `rubberband`

```
ffplay -i interview.wav -af "rubberband=tempo=1.0:pitch=1.5:pitchq=quality"
```

You may want to play around with the `transients` variable of this option as well.

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-rubberband

Edit:
if you're unfamiliar with ffmpeg and ffplay, the `ffmpeg` command line would be:

`ffmpeg -i input.wav -af "rubberband=tempo=1.0:pitch=1.5:pitchq=quality" output.wav`

If you require details of some other method, other than the command line, you will have to specify what method you are using, preferably with a code sample of what you have tried so far. (edit your question, don't add another comment)

Comment: Thanks alot for your kind response but please clear only one issue,

Comment: should i write my command like ,"ffplay","-i",inputfile.wav,"-af","rubberband=tempo=1.0:pitch=1.5:pitchq=quality" ?

Comment: @syedkashifullah Rolf's updated their answer btw - the example is using quotes around that set of options, so you might have to escape your string or use a raw string: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/strings.html#string-literals But exactly what you need depends on what you're doing, that's why Rolf's asking to see the code you're using to call *ffmpeg*

Comment: can you please help out changing pitch and tempo through ffmpeg of an example raw audio file, with ffmpeg Execution ?

Comment: @syedkashifullah What is this "raw audio" file? Your question was about an .mp3 file and Whilst I admit my examples were .wav, all you had to do was replace .wav with .mp3 but raw audio data is completely different. Check: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/audio%20types

Comment: thanks Rolf but I want to ask one last thing

Comment: I added these two lib for FFMPEG integration but what will i suppose to do when adding rubberband. Please help:implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full-gpl:4.4.LTS'
    implementation 'nl.bravobit:android-ffmpeg:1.1.7'

Comment: @syedkashifullah All of that went completely over my head. I've no idea. Try reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44795258/ffmpeg-on-android-with-rubberband

Comment: Hi Rolf, could you please check the code I have uploaded here and help me find what mistake I am making here, because I am still unable to change pitch and tempo of an mp3 audio file.

Comment: Sorry, no as java is not my thing. If you now have the command running off the command line, your best bet is to ask a new question, with the code that does not work. Be sure to give the full error message if there is one. Remember to give the working command line instruction as well.